# Different ObjectMapper / ObjectMapperCustomizer for client and service implementations

Tags: quarkus, resteasy, reactive

Quarkus allows a program to use specify a custom Jackson ObjectMapper by using CDI producer method or customize the ObjectMapper with ObjectMapperCustomizer instances.

I need to have different behaviors for RestEasy Reactive Client use and RestEasy Reactive use.  Specifically, I want the service implementation to be set with
`.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, true)` and the client to have `.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)`

Is it possible to achieve this in Quarkus version 2.7.1.Final?

Comment: This is not currently possible, but sounds like a reasonable request. Mind opening an issue on GitHub asking for the feature?

Comment: [Issue 23979](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23979) created

Comment: You could wrap up your custom object mappers into separate beans, and work with those beans instead. For example, I needed a `new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory())`, I made a `@Named` service that produces it.